# Using NSMutableAttributedString as a Constant in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsstring, constants

I just started to learn Swift and came across something I don't understand. In a tutorial the author creates a `NSMutableAttributedString` within a constant. Later on that constant is altered. What I don't understand is how this is possible without getting any errors. Does `NSMutableAttributedString` somehow, for lack of a better term, override the rules of a constant?

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let title = sender.titleForState(.Normal)!
    let plainText = "\(title) button pressed"
    let styledText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: plainText)
    let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(statusLabel.font.pointSize)]
    let nameRange = (plainText as NSString).rangeOfString(title)
    styledText.setAttributes(attributes, range: nameRange)

    statusLabel.attributedText = styledText
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `NSMutableAttributedString`, but with the fact that `styledText` stores a reference type. Since it is defined as constant, you can't change its value :

```
styledText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "anotherString") // Error
```

But you can make changes to the instance the variable points to.

The `let` keyword in Swift enforces immutability for value types (Structures and Enumerations), not for reference types.

**Structures and Enumerations in Swift have two types of methods:**

- Mutating methods, which are defined using the keyword `mutating`
- Non-mutating methods (default behavior)

If you assign an instance of a structure or enumeration to a mutable storage (something you have defined using `var`), you're free to modify the state of it by calling any mutating or non-mutating method on it.

If you assign it to a immutable storage (defined using `let`), then you can only call the non-mutating methods on it. You cannot make the storage store another instance either (i.e, you can't assign another struct or enum to it).

Classes, being reference types, don't have the notion of  mutating or non-mutating methods.